# CSS - Image alignment

Tags: css, image, css-tables

Can I do this without using tables, or is tables the best solution?

Each numbered box is a different piece of image:

```
   ___________________
   |       |    2    |
   |       |_________|
   |   1   |  3 |  4 |
   |       |____|____|
   |       |    5    |
   |_______|_________|
```

Comment: tables should be used to display data.. yes... you could use tables to align, but that is not elegant and that may depend in how validated you'd like your code to be. If you want html5 then tables are invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using floats as long as your container has a defined width. So an example might look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img1.jpg" />
  <img src="img2.jpg" />
  <img src="img3.jpg" />
  <img src="img4.jpg" />
  <img src="img5.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

And your css would be:

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
}

img {
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

As long as your images are built at the proper widths and heights, then that should do the trick.

Comment: Amazed such an easy solution worked. Didn't even need the "clear" div under it. (Maybe something lower served its purpose.) Thanks!

Comment: The "clear" div clears those floats so that anything beyond your container doesn't accidentally get pulled into the flow.

Floats were intended to be used to float images within paragraphs, so other content generally flows around anything floated. Clearing the floats breaks that content flow.

Comment: @imsiso, if this isn't a "general" solution, then I'm not sure what  would be. This shows an example of html, and the css to style that html. There's really no more "general" way of answering the question.

Comment: @Steve - I mean as the way we use in creating a tableless template with divs ,css and after that we will put each image as a content of that section. - but you are right that's not a thing you can learn it to sb in a post. and +1

Comment: It is not only general but also clean, the only risk here is the size of the pictures, if they have the pics 3 and 4 overflow the width then they will be pushed down. As long as the pictures are well sized this should work.